# Form errors cannot be set after form validation has finished. When trying to edit user password in webform presave hook

Tags: 8, users, webforms

I'am trying to edit a user account based on the values submitted through webform, the webform is Ajax enabled and I'am using the following code to achieve this.

```
function hook_webform_submission_presave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
  if ($webform_submission->getWebform()->id() == 'profile_edit') { 
         $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id()); 
         $webform_data = $webform_submission->getData();
          if(!empty($webform_data['email'])){
              $user->set('mail',$webform_data['email']);
          }
          if(!empty($webform_data['password'])){
              $user->set('pass',$webform_data['password']);
          }
            if(!empty($webform_data['mobile_no_'])){
              $user->set('field_mobile',$webform_data['mobile_no_']);
          }
          if(!empty($webform_data['cover_photo'])){
              $user->set('field_cover_picture',$webform_data['cover_photo']);
          }
          if(!empty($webform_data['profile_image'])){
              $user->set('user_picture',$webform_data['profile_image']);
          }
          if(!empty($webform_data['user_name'])){
              $user->set('name',$webform_data['user_name']);
          }
          $user->save();
     }
}
```

what happens is when I try to edit any other field except the password field everything works fine, but if I provide a value in the password field I receive a 500 response with the following error message:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.LogicException: Form errors cannot be set after form validation has finished. in Drupal\Core\Form\FormState->setErrorByName() (line 1057 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormState.php). Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->setInvalidTokenError(Object) (Line: 868)

The password field in the webform is of type password and there is no confirm password field.

Comment: Try with `$user->setPassword($webform_data['password']);` instead of `$user->set('pass',$webform_data['password']);`

Comment: I tried but no luck :(

Comment: How did you add webform  password field ?

Comment: I have tested your code with textfield it works, Please add how you added the  password field to webform

Comment: I have used the webform password field, Instead of textfield.

Comment: I have used the webform password field, Instead of textfield. I have enabled the password element in webform configurations by using the following URL http:mysite.com/admin/structure/webform/config/elements and then used the password element.

Comment: I think it's not caused by password field, i have tested it it works, so try to comment all, and test one by one .

Comment: I think it was an issue with the webform. I created a new form and applied this code it worked... Thanks bro.. @berramou

Comment: welcome bro, glad i help.